# Clickable Menus Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

At the moment I am developing a menu for our sales sheet. The goal is to click on a menu item and jump right to that cell in Google Sheets (see it as a content menu for a large Sheets document).

At the moment I got a menu working were I have a manual input so my colleagues can go to that cell. I have divided them in 5 variables whom all need to be clickable (and no manual input). As an extra all these cells need to somehow be permanent so when I ad a row I dont have to edit the script again. Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Here is the code:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Inhoudsopgave')
      .addItem('Uren', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Marge','menuItem2')
      .addSeparator()   
      .addItem('Omzet','menuItem3')
      .addSeparator()  
      .addItem('Bonus','menuItem4')
      .addSeparator()  
      .addItem('Pie Charts','menuItem5')  
      .addToUi();
}
function menuItem1(){
  var strRange = Browser.inputBox("Om naar UREN te gaan vul dan in A2:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(strRange != "cancel")
  {
    try
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(strRange).activate();
    }
    catch(e) {Browser.msgBox(e.message);}
  }
}
function menuItem2(){
  var strRange = Browser.inputBox("Om naar MARGE te gaan vul dan in A191:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(strRange != "cancel")
  {
    try
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(strRange).activate();
    }
    catch(e) {Browser.msgBox(e.message);}
  }
}
function menuItem3(){
  var strRange = Browser.inputBox("Om naar OMZET te gaan vul dan in A382:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(strRange != "cancel")
  {
    try
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(strRange).activate();
    }
    catch(e) {Browser.msgBox(e.message);}
  }
}
function menuItem4(){
  var strRange = Browser.inputBox("Om naar BONUS te gaan vul dan in A579:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(strRange != "cancel")
  {
    try
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(strRange).activate();
    }
    catch(e) {Browser.msgBox(e.message);}
  }
}
function menuItem5(){
  var strRange = Browser.inputBox("Om naar PIE CHARTS te gaan vul dan in A797:", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  if(strRange != "cancel")
  {
    try
    {
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(strRange).activate();
    }
    catch(e) {Browser.msgBox(e.message);}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with google docs, but I recommend starting by implementing the DRY principle.

```
function menuItem1() {
    openMenuItem('UREN', 'A191');
}

function openMenuItem(title, cell) {
    var strRange = Browser.inputBox("Om naar " + title + " te gaan vul dan in " + cell + ":", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

    if(strRange != "cancel") {
        try {
            SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(strRange).activate();
        }
        catch(e) {
            Browser.msgBox(e.message);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure what language google docs uses, I assume javascript based on your example, but if not, how to concatenate strings with variables as I did in the first line of openMenuItem is something you will have to look up :)

Comment: Daniel: Your assumption is correct, Google Apps Script is JavaScript based so the DRY principle could be applied.

Answer (score 0):

With help from a friend i managed to solve the first challenge (no manual input):

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createMenu('Inhoudsopgave')
  .addItem('Uren', 'menuItem1')
  .addSeparator()
  .addItem('Marge','menuItem2')
  .addSeparator()   
  .addItem('Omzet','menuItem3')
  .addSeparator()  
  .addItem('Bonus','menuItem4')
  .addSeparator()  
  .addItem('Pie Charts','menuItem5')  
  .addToUi();
}
function menuItem1(){
  selectCell('A2');
}
function menuItem2(){
  selectCell('A191');
}
function menuItem3(){
  selectCell('A382');
}
function menuItem4(){
  selectCell('A581');
}
function menuItem5(){
  selectCell('A797');
}
function selectCell(cell){
  try
  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).activate();
  }
  catch(e) {
    Browser.msgBox(e.message);
  }
}
```

Now we got the challenge to make it so i dont have to adjust the variables every time i add a row. The idea is to let the script search for a specific line of text (i.e. MARGE1X) so it can find that cell everytime, anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: On this site it's not allowed to use answer posts to do follow-up questions as it's not possible to post an answer for an answer. Instead post a new question.

Comment: Instead of looking for specific text, could you name each range, then have the script look for the named range:  `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('Find1').activate();`?

Comment: Hey Ron, thanks for your reply. I tried to implement this in my code but can't get it to work. Do you have an example code i can see?